Is it normal for "complete -p git" to error until I autocomplete git first?
If I restart my terminal, I get an error when I type this:
$ complete -p git
bash: complete: git: no completion specification

But if I type git tab then run the complete command again, I get a different output:
$ complete -p git
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git

Once the shell becomes interactive, should complete -p git succeed on the first try, or is this working as designed?

For context, I'd like to call the __git_complete function in my .bashrc/.bash_profile to add autocompletion to my custom command, but it doesn't seem to exist until I autocomplete git first.
Also, I'm using cygwin on a Windows 10 machine, but I'm more interested in knowing how complete -p git works on other unix's.

Where is the completion for git that you use defined? Please describe what completion are you using.

I can't reproduce this. I get your first error, but tab makes no difference. Do you press tab when you're at complete -p git? Or do you type out git, press tab, then delete git and type in compete -p git? How exactly do you get to the second output (complete -o bashdefault...) you show?

Completion helper functions are autoloaded on first use. This avoids having to load a lot of code when bash starts for programs you might not even use. It also allows completion functions to be made available after bash has started (for a newly installed program).
You can see the dynamic completion loader by checking the setting for complete -D with complete -D -p. In practice, that's _completion_loader.
Thus your .bashrc needs the following lines in this order:
. /etc/bash_completion
_completion_loader git
… complete -p git …

